# Compile all file Typescript with Atom

Tags: javascript, compilation, typescript, atom-editor

I'm using TypeScript to make a backend application with node.js. I'm using as IDE the popular Atom with [Atom-Typescript plugin](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript). I'm loving it so far.

To compile it I'm using some boilerplate and con files I found on the Internet:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "outDir": "../build",
      "rootDir": ".",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ],
  "buildOnSave": true
}
```

Sometimes (quite frequently actually) I have to recompile everything via `tsc` shell command to via F6 key binding. It happens every time I pull workmate edits from remote git and when I add new files or sometimes I have to recompile for unknown reason.

All those problems let me think that I've missed some important configuration for the Typescript compiler.

Any hint?